# generate image tags in html for each object of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know my question might seem stupid but I am stuck with this bit of code and I struggle with Javascript.
I would like to be able to display inside my page some images from the text of some  links.
It might appear twisted but this is exactly what I want to do :-)
This is what I have managed to sort out so far if that can give you an idea :

```
<a href="#">http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png</a>
<a href="#">http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/png/section8-image.png</a>
<a href="#">http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png</a>
```

```
var liens = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
valeurs = [];

for (i = 0; i < liens.length; i += 1) { 
 if (liens[i].text) {        
    valeurs.push(liens[i].text);
    document.body.innerHTML = "<img src='" + valeurs[i] + "'>";
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're almost there. The most trivial fix for your code is to change this line:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<img src='" + valeurs[i] + "'>";
```

into this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<img src='" + valeurs[i] + "'>";
```

This will append to `innerHTML` instead of overwritng it.

A slightly better solution would be to actually create DOM nodes instead of modifying `innerHTML`. So the above line could be replaced by:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = valeurs[i];
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

You can check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mqvncLrf/)